# Is there any reason for no new Star Trek TV series for past nearly ten years?

Tags: star-trek

Next year we will "celebrate" **tenth** anniversary of airing last episodes of last [Star Trek TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_episodes).

Since I'm a Star Trek newbie, and I'm totally out of "surrounding rumors", can someone explain me, what is the real cause for this (if any)? Ten years is a vast amount of time.

Polish (my native) version of *Star Trek: Enterprise* Wikipedia article have even, somewhat "funny" (though completely outdated now) remark, that with cancellation of *StarTrek: Enterprise*, season 2005/2006  has become first for past eighteen years, that no new Star Trek TV episode was aried. Now we have eight more seasons like that. I think there should be some reason for that.

Note, that I read [this closed question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/96/7885) and most of its comments and I don't think mine falls into the same rule. Even, if there will be any new TV series produced and aired soon, thinkt, that my question will remain valid. It is interesting and should be interesting in future (at least to Star Trek newbies, like me): **What caused nearly ten years of no Star Trek TV series after eighteen years of uninterrupted trial of series after series**?

In other words, this question askes for reasons for <s>current</s> nearly ten years long situation, not if there will be any change to it (which would make the question off-topic and closed as cited one).

Comment: They kept making new Star Trek shows every year for 18 smegging years? **Why??** Reminds me of a sci-fi story I read where earth is contacted in the future by powerful space aliens, and they've been watching all of our old Star Trek shows, and the shows have stopped coming, and the aliens are here to demand that we produce more of them, *or else*.

Comment: I do wonder if the TV landscape has moved on somewhat. The big TV hits these days (Breaking Bad, The Wire, etc.) have movie-level production quality. Trying to match that *and* have the kind of effects work that a Star Trek series requires might be impractical/too expensive, especially when movies, with their superior production values, are so easily available at home. Would a new Star Trek series do as well as Game of Thrones?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Around when _Enterprise_ aired, the TV landscape was shifting slightly from "episodic" to "serialized" - in large part due to the huge popularity of [Lost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_(TV_series)).  Unfortunately, that's something Star Trek doesn't really "do":  Only DS9 was really successful at it, although ENT tried its best.  _Game of Thrones_ is more serial than episodic, and I suspect the same can be said of _Breaking Bad_ and _The Wire_ (although I've not seen them myself).

Comment: @Izkata: they absolutely are. And you’re quite right — Star Trek from TNG was specifically designed to not be serialised, so they could sell it into syndication more easily (I believe). I think DS9 was ahead of its time in that sense, although I guess Babylon 5 was right there with it.

Comment: Man, I miss Episodic TV.  No worrying about 'missing' parts of it, focused on quality with each episode rather than having to string it all together, absolutely no continuity between any episodes...okay so it wasn't all good but it wasn't all bad either.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Yes. Anything not set in the present day is expensive, because so many sets and costumes have to be made from scratch. That includes *Star Trek*, *Game of Thrones*, and historical dramas like *Boardwalk Empire*. And things like ST need even more makeup and special effects shots than *Game of Thrones*. ST's ratings had been declining for some time, so the network executives didn't think another series was a good financial bet. That said, I wouldn't rule out some kind of spin-off series from the new films if Paramount thinks there's money in it.

Comment: @Zibbobz I prefer it, I tend not to like movies much for the same reason that I don't care for episodic series as much:  It's harder for me to get invested in the characters.  They don't feel as real.

Comment: @Izkata It has its own merits too...which is as far as I'll say since we don't want to devolve this into a forum chat.

Comment: Based on what people in the industry have told me, the answer to “Why isn’t this on TV?” is most often: There isn’t a show runner willing to do it. (Although that begs the question of why...) If the people with the purse-strings trust the show runner, most other factors don’t really matter.

Comment: It's probably just as well... just about everything since "Enterprise" has been - literally - a step backwards.  Star Trek was originally about humanity advancing, and now we are doing prequels and reboots, for what?

Comment: Star Trek TV series went out of production for the same reason as almost all TV shows do. Enterprise, the last TV show of the franchise, suffered most severely from audience attrition. The show runners also seemed to be getting tired or possibly bored with it, or felt the franchise was getting over-exposed. There was some talk about giving it a rest for a few years before evaluating ideas for a new series. It doesn't help that Roddenberry's vision has been progressively eroded with the passing along of the showrunner baton over all the years.

Comment: If you count only regular "episodes" (not movies and not animated stuff) there was an almost *20* year gap between TOS and TNG.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've yet to hear any official source or information regarding that.

But I think one of the biggest problems for Star Trek is the franchise itself: "We've had that story before."

It's also apparent in the existing series (even TOS). Many stories always follow the same or a similar pattern with some slight variation. Also keep in mind that the three series from the 90's (and 80's) - TNG, DS9, and VOY - all co-existed in some way in the same timespan covering different aspects. In essence, they tried to tell different stories from different parts of space with different promises and settings. That worked rather well.

But at some point there isn't anything new to explore. Should they create a second TNG or DS9? I don't think that will work overall - it might feel too repetitive. And in-universe time goes on too. They can't tell new stories during timespans that got covered already (limits possibilities regarding global things happening). They already tried a prequel (with ENT) and they'd most likely run out of ideas and bad guys in case they create another sequel.

I see the biggest chance in new stories when taking the rebooted movies into consideration. But in the end this won't solve the whole "we've had that before". It just opens the possibility to retell known stories to add some variation (e.g. The Wrath of Khan and the latest movie).

Oh, and what could be interesting for me in some way: Creating a spin-off based on the whole temporal directive/timeship stuff introduced in VOY. It could get hard to find many huge and important problems supporting alterating the time line though. Plus I don't think they'd want to continue two different timelines (pun intended, more or less :)).

Edit: I think it's actually pretty safe to assume that [this related question and answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14215/what-was-the-reason-for-using-a-new-ship-instead-of-the-enterprise-in-stvoy) could almost be seen as some kind of duplicate. The only difference, back before *Star Trek: Voyager* they had that one idea they haven't done before.

Comment: A perfect answer as for me, thank you! Pity, that I can give you only +1 for this: "_they'd most likely run out of ideas and bad guys_", cause you made my day! :] However, I must disagree with you on the time-like spin-off idea. In my opinion, current VOY (and other) time-related, paradox-involved chapters are already too hard to understand by largest group of viewers (young Americans? :]). So making entire TV series around just this idea would be just perfect for trekkies, but would put entire production at financial risk, due to "the general" viewers group -- a private opinion.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot! You're asking about, with what new they could come? This is something on my mind for past few years. "_The Federation is at war_". Not the "war", which remains we see in DS9, but **WAR**. Make it (much) more mature, give us more blood, violence, hard decisions, situations, where there isn't right choice and choosing lesser evil is the only option, etc. Make a Star Trek, where airing each episode would require a "battle" with producers and TV managers (which would gave it much more audience, by paradox) etc. How do you find that?

Comment: What about an episode when they are on the holodeck and something goes wrong? oh. wait ...

Comment: @trejder Doctor Who is currently the most (commercially) successful it's ever been, and it's also more focused on paradoxes/time loops/etc. than ever before. I don't think time travel episodes were the fundamental problem with Voyager.

Comment: Voyager's time travel stuff most often has been some plot device or some random "event of the week". Voyager's *Year of Hell* would be a good example for this. Things like that always depend on how they tie in with previous/future episodes (if at all). Also there are many levels on how complex one episode could be (*Doctor Who* being a perfect example; sometimes time travel isn't obvious at all (or non-existant) and at other times they travel through time like every 4-5 seconds).

Comment: @trejder I'm not sure. It always depends on the actual concept. Doing such an episode similar to VOY's *Future's End* or TNG's *Time's Arrow* could be interesting - at least I'd give them a try.

Comment: @Mario _Year of Hell_ was planned by the writers to be an entire season, with no reset switch at the end.  They couldn't do it for various reasons, and were forced to compress it down to those two episodes.  Kes's visions may've been a good tie-in if it had come to pass.

Comment: @trejder The "Federation at war" idea would be a new, original take on the Star Trek franchise. A Decline and Fall of the Federation scenario would be fun, perhaps after a devastating war with the Borg or another species. The Federation, as well as the Klingon, Romulan, and Cardassian Empires have fallen into disarray and fragmented into independent worlds & sectors fighting for survival.

Comment: Another option for a new Star Trek series that would cut overhead costs without losing the cool F/X would be a CGI animated Star Trek series, similar to The Clone Wars and the upcoming Rebels series with the Star Wars franchise.

Comment: @evilsoup I don't say that time-travelling episodes are problem of VOY or any other ST. I'm just saying, that it requires much more "thinking" (in general way) and being much more focused, so can't be potentially addressed to "lesser minded" viewers (general description, no offend). For this reason, I found the idea of making entire ST series (or even season, as Izkata says) to commercially and financially risky. That's all. My opinion isn't related to any particular ST series.

Comment: @RobertF I don't think, that general idea of "Federation at war" or "Destruction of Federation" is new. I think, many has come with this idea. I'm just unsure, why it wasn't pushed further? But I think, it could be for the reasons, that I mentioned. Too violent, bloody, war-like episodes would force producers to deal with showing problems, TV managers resistance, content-rating organisations, etc. Again, it could be too commercially and financially risky.

Comment: They explored things like that in a few alternate timeline episodes (like in TNG; but also the TOS/DS9 parallel universe episodes in a way). I think it kinda works for a small feature/plot twist, but overall it doesn't really fit the whole Star Trek idea (at least Roddenberry's). They are explorers and it's always been a bit like wild west/frontiers in space, but they've never been conquistadors. That would more likely portrait the (TOS) Klingons. But yes, a more gruel/bloody approach would also mean more challenges to overcome and less viewership. I bet many here started watching ST as a kid.

Comment: @Mario Are you... suggesting a new Star Trek series that is centered around the Klingons, instead of Humans / The Federation?

Comment: @Michael Well, why not? Or how about **Married... with Ferengi Children**? ;)